# any class as function argument in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Suggestion needed:
As a newbie, I have class like below in **typescript**:

```
export declare class SampleOne extends Setting {
    getValue(): Promise<boolean>;
    setValue(value: boolean): Promise<void>;
}
```

And

```
export declare class SampleTwo extends Setting {
    getValue(): Promise<boolean>;
    setValue(value: boolean): Promise<void>;
}
```

Now i want a helper function where i can pass either **SampleOne** or **SampleTwo** like below:

```
async function getObj(title: string, categories: string, cname: Setting) {

    let obj = await et.findSetting(title,categories) as cname;// i want to pass either **SammpleOne** or **SampleTwo** class.
    return obj;
}
```

Function call would be like

**getObj(title, categories, SampleOne)**

**getObj(title, categories, SampleTwo)**

I am strangling to created this helper function.How it should be looks like in typescript??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to pass expected *type* of Setting, not the instance of it? (also, please post Setting for complete example)

Comment: yes only the type-sampleone or sampletwo not the instance.

Comment: @EricIpsum could you please share `et` object ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make `getObj` generic by the type of `Setting` and parametrize the last argument as a constructor of T:

```
type Class<T> = new (...args: any) => T;

async function getObj<T extends Setting>(
    title: string, categories: string, klass: Class<T>): Promise<T> 
{
    return .... as  T
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with [Convenience generic](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/generics#design-pattern-convenience-generic) pattern

```
async function getObj<T extends Setting>(title: string, categories: string): Promise<T> {
    let obj = await et.findSetting(title,categories) as T;
    return obj;
}
```

or, dropping the unncecessary async:

```
function getObj<T extends Setting>(title: string, categories: string): Promise<T> {
    return et.findSetting(title,categories) as Promise<T>;
}
```

Usage:

```
const s1 = getObj<SampleOne>('a', 'b');
```

Pros:

- can be used if you model Setting as a class
- can be used if you model Setting as an interface

Cons:

- no runtime check (which may or may not be a problem)

If you need runtime check and have settings modeled as classes,
you can use [Type](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/cfed0c0cf1238e5ad931598ce04c32f8c9a75143/packages/core/src/interface/type.ts#L35) (as coded by Angular folks):

```
interface Type<T> extends Function { new (...args: any[]): T; }

async function getObj<T extends Setting>(
    title: string, categories: string, klass: Type<T>): Promise<T> 
{
   let obj = await et.findSetting(title,categories);
   if (klass.prototype.isPrototypeOf(obj)) {
    return obj as T; 
   } else {
     throw new Error(`Expected ${klass.name} but got ${obj.constructor.name}`)
   }
   
}

const s1 = getObj('a', 'b', SampleOne);
s1.then(x => console.log(x))
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just apply this constraint `T extends typeof Setting` to generic:

```js
class Setting {
    getValue(): Promise<boolean> { return Promise.resolve(true) };
    setValue(value: boolean): Promise<void> { return Promise.resolve() };
}


class SampleOne extends Setting {
    getValue(): Promise<boolean> { return Promise.resolve(true) };
    setValue(value: boolean): Promise<void> { return Promise.resolve() };
}

class SampleTwo extends Setting {
    getValue(): Promise<boolean> { return Promise.resolve(true) };
    setValue(value: boolean): Promise<void> { return Promise.resolve() };
}

class DontAllowed { }

type AllowedClasses = typeof SampleOne | typeof SampleTwo

class SampleThree { // does not extends Setting
    getValue(): Promise<boolean> { return Promise.resolve(true) };
    setValue(value: boolean): Promise<void> { return Promise.resolve() };
}

function getObj<T extends typeof Setting>(cname: T) {
    return cname
}

const result = getObj(SampleOne) // ok
const result2 = getObj(SampleTwo) // ok
const result3 = getObj(DontAllowed) // expected error
```

In above example, I assumed that every class which extends Setting is allowed. If you want to allow anly two classes, you can do this thing:

```js
type AllowedClasses = typeof SampleOne | typeof SampleTwo

function getObj<T extends AllowedClasses>(cname: T) {
    return cname
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCmAXRBLAdgc2gbwFDQOgyQDUwQBXeACgEoAuaABQCcB7AWxQngB4AjNmxDwwaAHw5oLJBRZpm7LjwB0MiMIBuNRCyq1oAXwDc%20Qj0RlKNTeSqNBw0WgaLO3PprYoAJpOzSsvJuyvBq8Bog2nRGpoa4CaCQMLBgHAAOIgDyaPDQ8AAeiPBoPilIqJg4ZgTElnY0rqzuPAJCImL%20gYhyCs2h4ZHRuvqxNdAWVlTUttYO7c5NSh68Xr5dMj3B-R6DWo1j8bhJUHBpmfAAKgDubPlFJWVwFehYeIREpA10jDutjh0JFJNr0Qrt1PtqCN4AYTONJt9ZvZoADFr9lq01n5gUE%20hiwhCogc4UcTjAACJsNCIACCIBAbGu8B8UiOx3Ap1SGRElwAFjI8gEAPRC6A%20NgRaBoNiIe7FUrlZCvcZ1KaNdEtPiozo4rZ4zV7IlQvQwsYfBHWGYNeZOMRLTWrbzYgIg7b4w3RWFxBKIACe6TydIZTJ8AGEOTwYABeaB%20gNsABmZ258ByeQAPrH-fBE8mLjc2AkExQ0MBUFTPogsvwAFa8S5yx4wIOM5nh5IRcTUYBoNLwRiXAzvQiuhQ9vu4UlUiCy9QUECymN1as16hci5p2jHaeziLzxAAJmgS6QK7X5x5ty3wB3gQg%204AzMfK2fKdSWyHaEA)

I don't think that it is necessary to use type assertion (`as` operator) in such cases.

Comment: I don't think your code returns the right thing (`const result: typeof SampleOne`)

Answer (score 0):

Use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

```
async function getObj<T>(title: string, categories: string) {

    let obj = await et.findSetting(title,categories) as T;
    return obj;
}
```

Then you can call the function with the desired type:

```
getObj<SampleOne>('foo', 'bar');
getObj<SampleTwo>('foo', 'bar');
```